# Buttons are all linked to one button? Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have an expand button that expands text and hides it. However it only works for the first div, all the others link to the first button. Here is the JFiddle, to understand what i mean: https://jsfiddle.net/y52t87qe/

HTML:

```
<p class="info">Show to user</p>
<div class="hidden"><p class="info">Hide text, but show when the user clicks the button</p></div>

<button id="hide" onclick="btnChanger()">Expand</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".hidden").hide();

    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $(".hidden").toggle();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $(".hidden").show();
    });

});
```

is it that my button is an id, not a class? Im pretty unfamiliar with JQuery, so any help would be awesome :) thanks in advance! x

Comment: Duplicate `id`s set to `hide` ?

Comment: @guest271314 do i change that in the jquery? and how would i go by doing it? :P thank you though

Comment: See post for an approach substituting `class="hide"` for `id="hide"` , using `.prev(".hidden")` to select closest `.hidden` element , removing `onclick` from `html` , setting `html` from `"Hide"` to `"Expand"` with `.html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem with your code is, ID of an element must be unique.

So use classes to work with similar elements like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.hide').click(function() {
    var hidden = $(this).text() == 'Expand';
    $(this).siblings('.hidden').toggle(hidden);
    $(this).text(hidden ? 'Hide' : 'Expand')
  })
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-video-1">
  <h3>Introduction</h3>
  <h4 class="h4-home">Communication</h4> 
  <p class="info">Show to user</p>
  <div class="hidden">
    <p class="info">Hide text, but show when the user clicks the button</p>
  </div>
  <button class="hide">Expand</button>
</div>
<div id="home-video-2">
  <h3>Introduction</h3>
  <h4 class="h4-home">Communication</h4> 
  <p class="info">Show to user</p>
  <div class="hidden">
    <p class="info">Hide text, but show when the user clicks the button</p>
  </div>
  <button class="hide">Expand</button>
</div>
<div id="home-video-3">
  <h3>Introduction</h3>
  <h4 class="h4-home">Communication</h4> 
  <p class="info">Show to user</p>
  <div class="hidden">
    <p class="info">Hide text, but show when the user clicks the button</p>
  </div>
  <button class="hide">Expand</button>
</div>
<div id="home-video-4">
  <h3>Introduction</h3>
  <h4 class="h4-home">Communication</h4> 
  <p class="info">Show to user</p>
  <div class="hidden">
    <p class="info">Hide text, but show when the user clicks the button</p>
  </div>
  <button class="hide">Expand</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! Works great :D xo

Comment: does this only work for paragraphs <p></p> ? (will it not work for <ul><li></li></ul> ?)

Comment: @BriannaXD can you share the update html.. if the structure of the html changes the dom traversal logic also need to be changed

Comment: its okay, im just using <p> with <br> thanks heaps though :D xx

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/y52t87qe/4/)

```
$(".hidden").hide();
$(".hide").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('div').toggle();
})
```

Change duplicated id to class

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `class="hide"` for `id="hide"` ,removing `onclick` from `html` , single `.click()` event , `.prev(".hidden")` selector to toggle previous `.hidden` element , `.html()` to set `"Hide"` , `"Expand"` `html`

```
$(".hide").click(function(){
  $(this).html(this.innerHTML === "Expand" ? "Hide" : "Expand")
  .prev(".hidden").toggle();
});
```

```js
$(".hidden").hide(); 
    $(".hide").click(function(){
        $(this).html(this.innerHTML === "Expand" ? "Hide" : "Expand").prev(".hidden").toggle();
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ICT and Defence - Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Oswald|Pacifico|Bangers|Anton|Sigmar One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <style>
    #home-nav {
      border-bottom: 2px solid;
    }
  </style>


</head>

<body>
  <!---JavaScript SDK // For Social Media -->
  <!---End of JavaScript -->

  <!--header moite-->
  <header>

    <div id="header-container">
      <h1>ICT and Defence</h1>
    </div>
    <!--Navigation-->
    <nav>
      <div id="nav-wrapper">
        <ul id="main-menu">
          <li><a id="home-nav" href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a id="communication-nav" href="communication.html">Communication</a>
          </li>
          <li><a id="drones-nav" href="drones.html">Drones</a>
          </li>
          <li><a id="future-nav" href="future.html">Future Soldiers</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div id="container">

    <div id="center-div">

      <div id="home-video">
        <h3>Introduction</h3>
        <h4 class="h4-home">Communication</h4> 
        <p class="info">The first military communications included the utilization of runners or the sending and receiving of simple signs, basic encrypted messages were sometimes used to conceal the information only for the onlooker.</p>
        <div class="hidden">
          <p class="info">The first distinctive employments of military interchanges were called "signals". Cutting edge units work in these strategies are typically assigned as "sign corps". The Roman arrangement of military correspondence is an early case of this.
            Later, the expressions "signs" and "signaller" got to be words alluding to an exceedingly unmistakable military occupation managing general specialized systems (like those in common utilization) instead of with weapons.</p>
        </div>

        <button class="hide">Expand</button>


      </div>

      <div id="home-video2">
        <h4 class="h4-home">Drones</h4> 
        <p class="info">The first military communications included the utilization of runners or the sending and receiving of simple signs, basic encrypted messages were sometimes used to conceal the information only for the onlooker.</p>
        <div class="hidden">
          <p class="info">The first distinctive employments of military interchanges were called "signals". Cutting edge units work in these strategies are typically assigned as "sign corps". The Roman arrangement of military correspondence is an early case of this.
            Later, the expressions "signs" and "signaller" got to be words alluding to an exceedingly unmistakable military occupation managing general specialized systems (like those in common utilization) instead of with weapons.</p>
        </div>

        <button class="hide">Expand</button>

      </div>

      <div id="home-video3">
        <h4 class="h4-home">Future Soldiers</h4> 
        <p class="info">The first military communications included the utilization of runners or the sending and receiving of simple signs, basic encrypted messages were sometimes used to conceal the information only for the onlooker.</p>
        <div class="hidden">
          <p class="info">The first distinctive employments of military interchanges were called "signals". Cutting edge units work in these strategies are typically assigned as "sign corps". The Roman arrangement of military correspondence is an early case of this.
            Later, the expressions "signs" and "signaller" got to be words alluding to an exceedingly unmistakable military occupation managing general specialized systems (like those in common utilization) instead of with weapons.</p>
        </div>

        <button class="hide">Expand</button>

      </div>


      <!---
   <div id="home-video2">
    <h4 class="h4-home">Communication</h4>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/G2_Q9FoD-oQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <p class="info">158,962,555,217,826,360,000 (Enigma Machine) - Numberphile</p>
   </div>
   
   <div id="home-video3">
    <h4 class="h4-home">Future Of Defence</h4>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S3VIpw0HAko" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <p class="info">Top 10 Futuristic Military Weapons in Development</p>
   </div>
   -->
    </div>



  </div>


  <footer>
    <p>KIT106 - Assignment 2</p>
  </footer>




</body>

</html>
```